# Memory mapping in Assembly and its contents

Tags: memory, assembly, memory-address, 68000

I have two 68000 registers `A2` and `A7`.  Initially `A2` contains `$002C4178` and `A7` contains `$0000A000`.  Then, the following instructions execute in sequence:

```
 MOVE.L #6,-(A2)
 MOVE.L #14,-(A7)
 MOVE.L #$24,(A7)
 MOVE.L (A7),$1000
```

What are the contents of the changed memory?  What are the contents of the registers `A2` and `A7` (in hex)?

Comment: What do you think the answer might be ?

Comment: I don't have any idea. I am a beginner just started practicing such questions.

Answer (score 2):

`A2` is pre-decremented in the first instruction, so:

```
$002C4178 => $002C4174
```

then #6 is stored at this address.

Then `A7` is pre-decremented, so:

```
$0000A000 => $00009FFC
```

then `#14` is stored at this address. This is then immediately overwritten by the next instruction, which writes `#$24` (`#36`) at the same address.

Finally the value above in the location pointed at by `A7` (`#$24`) is stored at absolute address `$1000`.